# Prove that $M_i'-m_i' \leq M_i-m_i$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f$ be a bounded function on $[a,b]$ and let $\mathcal{P}$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. Define $M_i$ and $m_i$ to be the supremums and infimums for a partition $\mathcal{P}$ over $[x_i,x_{i-1}]$. Similarly let $M_i'$ and $m_i'$ have analagous definitions for $\left|f\right|$. Prove that $M_i'-m_i' \leq M_i-m_i$.

I thought we have $M_i' \geq M_i$ and $m_i' \geq m_i$ because of the absolute value sign, but this seems to contradict the result in the question. I am then confused what I did wrong.

Comment: Your inequalities are correct.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo. Are they still right?

Comment: Yes, since $|f(x)| \ge f(x)$. I have added a straightforward proof below.

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be the interval in question, and drop the $i$ subscript to simplify
notation.

Note that we always have
$|f(x)| \le |f(y)| + |f(x)-f(y)|$, and so
$|f(x)| - |f(y)| \le |f(x)-f(y)|$.

Hence $\sup_{x,y} (|f(x)| - |f(y)|) \le \sup_{x,y} |f(x)-f(y)| = \sup_{x,y} (f(x)-f(y))$.

Expanding, this gives
$\sup_x |f(x)| - \inf_y |f(y)| \le \sup_x f(x) - \inf_y f(y) $, or
$M'-m' \le M-m$.

Comment: Note that $|f(x)-f(y)| = |f(y)-f(x)|$, so on the left hand side we can always assume that $f(x) \ge f(y)$.

Comment: I don't think it was necessary to use the variable $y$ here. You could've just used $x$ and gotten the same result.

Comment: I have no idea what your comment means. Whatever letters are used, at least two are necessary to disambiguate.

Comment: I mean $\sup_x |f(x)| - \inf_x |f(x)| \le \sup_x f(x) - \inf_x f(x) $ implies the result.

Comment: Sure, but it would have been more work to type :-).

Comment: I mean you don't even need the variable $y$. We could use $x$ for that reason.

Comment: Well, when I wrote $\sup_{x,y}$ I **need** both variables. Then I just cut & paste and make functional changes. I don't really follow why the 'dummy' variable is an issue.

Comment: It isn't an issue. What you did is fine; I am just pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

If $f = |f|$ in the interval, equality is clear.

If $|f| = -f$ in the interval, then use the fact that $\sup A = -\inf (-A)$ where $-A$ is the set of additive inverses of elements of $A$. Letting $A$ be the image of $f$ in the interval, we get $M_i'-m_i' = M_i-m_i$.

The last case is where $f$ changes signs in the interval. In this case, the infimum of $|f|$ is at least $0$ (if $f$ is continuous it is $0$). The supremum is $\max(|M_i|, |m_i|)$. In any case, since $M_i$ and $m_i$ have different signs, $\max(|M_i|, |m_i|) - 0 \leq M_i-m_i$. If the infimum is greater than $0$ our ineqality is only strengthened.